# How to get the profile and cover picture from gmail account on android programmatically

Tags: android

Actually, I am developing an app with a **navigation drawer**. So, I need one profile picture and one background picture to make it charming. Google account is best in this case at least in my eyesight. So, I need to get the profile picture and cover picture from **primary gmail account** of an android device. Can anyone help me please? I'll be very much helped after all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Google Android API to integrate Sign-in of primary gmail account into your app. Refer the official google sign-in documentation [Google Sign-In for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/)

After following the above documentation, you can get the profile information(display name and profile image) by belowed code :

`GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
String personId = acct.getId();
Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();`

Comment: Thanks dude. I got it.

Comment: Enjoy happy coding :-)